# R: applying xts function for few columns

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

I'm trying to apply "dsa" function to my data. The problem is that it is applicable only for one first column of it, even though I putting all as x. Is it any method how to apply to all columns? My code:

```
df <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Weather.csv")
data <- within(df, rm(Date, ï..DATE))
#install.packages("dsa")

library(dsa)
library(xts)
daily_demand_timeserie <- xts(x = data,
                          order.by = df$Date,
                          frequency=365)
adjusted <- dsa(series = daily_demand_timeserie)
```

The data:
[image]